# can't MAKE tensorflow Raspberry pi examples

Tags: tensorflow, makefile, raspberry-pi

I installed tensorflow on the Raspberry Pi 3, running Jessie and did that in two ways, via the .whl file / pip install for Python 2.7.:

https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi

as well as a full compile via:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile

Both installs (I did them on different OS images) where successfull and went through without error.

Next, I wanted to compile the official Raspberry Pi examples from tensorflow's git repository:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples

However, none of the examples does compile (neither the camera example nor the image recognition), both give the same error and Google doesn't tell me anything:

```
make -f tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/Makefile gcc --std=c++11
-O0 -I/usr/local/include -I. -I/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/../../makefile/downloads
-I/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/../../makefile/downloads/eigen/
-I/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/../../makefile/gen/proto/
-I/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/../../makefile/gen/proto_text/
-c tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/camera.cc -o /home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/gen/obj/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/camera.o
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/platform/mutex.h:31:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:31,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/camera.cc:33:
./tensorflow/core/platform/default/mutex.h:25:22: fatal error:
nsync_cv.h: No such file or directory  #include "nsync_cv.h"
                      ^ compilation terminated. tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/Makefile:80: recipe for target
'/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/gen/obj/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/camera.o'
failed make: ***
[/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/gen/obj/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/camera/camera.o]
Error 1
```

as well as:

```
make -f tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/Makefile gcc
--std=c++11 -O0 -I/usr/local/include -I. -I/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/../../makefile/downloads
-I/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/../../makefile/downloads/eigen/
-I/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/../../makefile/gen/proto/
-I/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/../../makefile/gen/proto_text/
-c tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/label_image.cc -o /home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/gen/obj/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/label_image.o
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/platform/mutex.h:31:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:31,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/label_image.cc:33:
./tensorflow/core/platform/default/mutex.h:25:22: fatal error:
nsync_cv.h: No such file or directory  #include "nsync_cv.h"
                      ^ compilation terminated. tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/Makefile:79: recipe for
target
'/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/gen/obj/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/label_image.o'
failed make: ***
[/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/gen/obj/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/label_image.o]
Error 1
```

How can I locate / add / compile "nsync_cv.h"?
And btw:

```
export HOST_NSYNC_LIB=`tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_nsync.sh`
```

gives me:

```
g++ -M -std=c++11 -DNSYNC_USE_CPP11_TIMEPOINT -DNSYNC_ATOMIC_CPP11
-I../../platform/c++11 -I../../platform/gcc -I../../platform/posix -pthread -I../../public -I../../internal ../../internal/*.c ../../testing/*.c ../../platform/c++11/src/nsync_semaphore_mutex.cc
../../platform/c++11/src/per_thread_waiter.cc
../../platform/c++11/src/yield.cc
../../platform/c++11/src/time_rep_timespec.cc
../../platform/c++11/src/nsync_panic.cc \
          ../../platform/c++11/src/start_thread.cc > dependfile make: 'nsync.a' is up to date.
```

Comment: Run `find / -type f -name nsync_cv.h 2>/dev/null`. What is the output? (I.e., does the required header file even exist on your system?)

Comment: I got this:/home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/public/nsync_cv.h
Maybe, the touble tensorflow dir in my home dir is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I once compiled tensorflow with the makefile on a nvidia Jetson TX1 and I could compile and run the examples by adding some lines to the Makefiles of the examples:

1. after line 18:

   NSYNCLIBDIR := $(TFMAKEFILE_DIR)/downloads/nsync/builds/default.linux.c++11 !!!change folder default.linux.c++11 to where your libnsync.a is!!!

   NSYNCLIBS := $(NSYNCLIBDIR)/libnsync.a
2. after line 26:

   NSYNC := $(TFMAKEFILE_DIR)/downloads/nsync/public/
3. after line 36:

   -L$(NSYNCLIBDIR) \
4. after line 43:

   -I$(NSYNC) \
5. after line 51:

   -lnsync \
6. change line 72 to:

   $(EXECUTABLE_NAME): $(EXECUTABLE_OBJS) $(TFLIBS) $(NSYNCLIBS)

Hope it works with that changes, good luck :)

Comment: Please [edit] this question and clean up the formatting to make it more readable.